# Prerequisite maths for 'Statistical Inference' by Casella and Berger

Tags: probability, statistics, book-recommendation

I want to improve my knoweldge of statistics (part pleasure, part work) and have been recommended *'Statistical Inference'* by Casella and Berger as a good foundation text at the undergraduate level (also *'Probability and Random Processes'* by Grimmett and Stirzaker).

I graduated in science, not mathematics, and feel it assumes a level of maths I don't have, for example, on sigma algebra the line *"...it follows that B is closed under countable intersections."* really threw me as I've not encountered the term before. That aside, a lot of the probability I've skimmed through looks familiar so I don't think I'm too far off the start line.

Are there any maths subjects, even at the high school level, that are worth revising/learning before working through this book? My calculus is OK, so I'm guessing something on sets? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Grimmett is actually a really good book on probability which covers the necessary background set theory and the like. I might recommend reading up to about Chapter 7 in Grimmet before doing Casella and Berger. The nice thing is it’s a book _about probability_ not about all of the machinery needed to eventually do probability, so it’s more beginner friendly than something that throws sigma algebras at you paragraph one.

Comment: Thanks @eepperly16. Is there another branch of maths that gives a more gentle introduction to sigma algebras? It feels like I'm missing a tool box to understand them. I've got both books so I'll follow your advice.

Comment: The other big area of math which uses $\sigma$-algebras is graduate-level real analysis, and that is certainly not going to be a more gentle introduction than you'll find in _Grimmet_. To supplement, [here](http://abstract.ups.edu/aata/section-sets-and-equivalence-relations.html) is a good general reference for sets and functions and stuff (the section on proofs earlier is also good.) It's where I learned most of this stuff.

Comment: Thank you so much @eepperly16, thats helped me so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is a text for Master's students. DON'T use this as your first introduction to Statistics.  PreRequisites are

- [Introduction to Proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/606590), like [*Book of Proof* by Richard Hammack](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3316157).
- [MultiVariable Calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3993177).
- A first book on [Probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1183481), like [*Introduction to Probability* by Blitzstein and Hwang.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4372395)
- A first book on Mathematical Statistics, like [*An Introduction to Mathematical Statistics and Its Applications* by Larsen and Marx](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3059347).
- Linear Algebra.
- [Real Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4578478).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).