# Book recommendation for proof?

Tags: book-recommendation

I now realize that a big part of higher mathematics is proof construction, and it is an area I would like to get familiar with.

I have found the book ‘how to prove it’ by Velleman, but am wondering if anyone has any other suggestions for proof.

In terms of difficulty I am looking for a book of relative ease as I am new to proof. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/38854).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a list of freely available books I know, but since I've personally learnt proofs before most of them were written, I am no good judge of their quality as proof tutorials:

- [Eric Lehman, F Thomson Leighton, Albert R Meyer, *Mathematics for Computer Science*](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/spring18/mcs.pdf). Part I is specifically about proofs, and parts II and III should provide good practice. It's written for MIT students, so it might be a bit fast-going, but it's written in an enjoyable lively style (most math books either avoid or fail at jokes; this one is an exception).
- [Martin V. Day, *An Introduction to Proofs and the Mathematical Vernacular*](https://www.math.vt.edu/people/day/ProofsBook/IPaMV.pdf) ([archive.org mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180712152432/https://www.math.vt.edu/people/day/ProofsBook/IPaMV.pdf)). Big upside (to me) is that it does determinants in detail. A downside is that it mis-defines polynomials as functions.
- [Daniel J. Velleman, *How to prove it*, 2nd edition 2006](http://users.metu.edu.tr/serge/courses/111-2011/textbook-math111.pdf). This seems to be slow and systematic, but (as a consequence) doesn't get far enough to prove anything really exciting. This is, of course, a common problem with introductions to proofs, particularly when they are written for 1-semester courses.
- [Richard Hammack, *Book of proof*](https://www.people.vcu.edu/%7Erhammack/BookOfProof/). Roughly same level as Velleman, from its look.
- [Clive Newstead, *An Infinite Descent into Pure Mathematics*](https://infinitedescent.xyz/). Still a work in progress. This goes deeper than most other comparable texts into combinatorics (e.g., the "path-dependent product rule" for counting is formalized and proven!).
- [Paolo Aluffi, *Introduction to Advanced Mathematics*](http://web.archive.org/web/20190421073943/www.math.hawaii.edu/%7Epavel/Aluffi_notes.pdf). These are lecture notes (though they seem reasonably polished), and also suffer from the "not getting anywhere too interesting" syndrome (see Velleman), but Aluffi is known for enjoyable writing.
- [James Aspnes, *Notes on Discrete Mathematics*](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/classes/202/notes.pdf). This is written from a TCS point of view (e.g., page 41 is a table of the rules of natural deduction), but it covers the usual ground along with some graph theory and enumerative combinatorics. Aspnes writes well (here are [notes on introductory programming, C++ and Linux](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/classes/223/notes.html)).
- [Matthias Beck and Ross Geoghegan, *The Art of Proof: Basic Training For Deeper Mathematics*](https://matthbeck.github.io/aop.html).
- [Alistair Savage, *MAT1362 Mathematical reasoning and proofs*](https://alistairsavage.ca/mat1362/notes/MAT1362-Mathematical_reasoning_and_proofs.pdf). These notes are written for a course that follows [Beck and Geoghegan](https://matthbeck.github.io/aop.html), so can be regarded as an expanded version of parts of the latter, including proofs that are omitted from the latter. See [Savage's teaching page](https://alistairsavage.ca/teaching/) for more notes.
- [Ted Sundstrom, *Mathematical Reasoning: Writing and Proof*](https://www.tedsundstrom.com/mathematical-reasoning-writing-and-proof).
- [Franco Vivaldi, *Mathematical writing for undergraduate students*](https://web.archive.org/web/20210126130243/http://www.thinkingwriting.qmul.ac.uk/sites/default/files/shared/files/Mathematical%20Writing%20for%20undergraduates%20Vivaldi.PDF). This is likely a draft of [his 2014 book](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9781447165262).

These are just the ones I have found in my personal library and freely available on the internet; if I had listed the paywalled ones, this post would be again as long. As I said, I have not actually learned proofs myself from any of these, so all I can offer are quick judgments based on leafing through.

Comment: This is a great compilation for me so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**Mathematical Thinking, Problem-Solving and Proofs**, by John P. D'Angelo, Douglas B. West

I borrowed it from a local library, and like it very much.
In fact, I now own a hard-cover copy !

Comment: Ok, thanks, looks like a good book for what I want.

Answer (score -1):

*[Proofs from the Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_from_THE_BOOK)* by Aigner and Ziegler comes to mind.

It contains many elegant proofs spanning different topics.

Comment: But is it a good book for exercises and practising writing your own proofs at an introductory level?

Comment: @Arthur Of course not, however it is a great book for getting a ''feel'' for some proof techniques

Comment: I’m looking more for a book, that focuses on proof writing, but this book may be an interesting read whilst I’m more familiar with proof.

Comment: It is, in my experience, absolutely *not* a novice-level text.