# Comparison of textbooks on "how to write proofs"

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

Next fall I will teach a class on "How to write proofs". Prerequisite is first-year calculus.  The three textbooks I am considering are

- Hammack, Book of Proofs (3rd ed)
- Sundstrom, Mathematical Reasoning: Writing and Proof (3rd ed)
- Cummings, Proofs: A long-form mathematics textbook.

This will be my first time teaching such a course, and I'd like to get inputs and comments from those who have used/are familiar with these *specific books*.

Note:  I am aware of prior posts such as [Book recommendation for proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3316114/book-recommendation-for-proof) and  https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/13034/book-request-teaching-proving-and-reasoning-at-an-american-university  The posts there are either lists of books and/or recommendation for a specific book.  What I am looking for are comments and comparison about the *three specific ones listed above*, especially from those who have taught such classes using these specific books.  THANKS!

EDIT:  I was asked to clarify what information I am looking for, so here it is:  Based on quick peeks at the three books, here are my first impressions:

- Sundstrom and Hammack provide free downloads and Cummings is in-expensive, so cost is not an issue.
- Sundstrom is the only the one that provides instructor solution manual.  I can obviously solve all the problems, but having solutions available does have me in picking problems for homework (e.g. length of solution, complications/tricky spots etc) and lecture preparation.
- Sundstrom is (relatively speaking) the most 'old-fashion' of the three.  There is not a lot of motivation of the materials, and the "beginning activities" at the start of each sections, while helpful for lecture planning, in a way "dilute" the materials, and I worry that it might makes it harders for students to pick out information they need.  I also wish that (very basic) set theory were presented in chap 1, and I find it a bit strange that congruence got covered before equivalence relations.  (please remember that these are my first impressions)
- Cummings is the opposite of that:  Very fresh and lively, and the presentation/examples are interesting.  At the same time the exposition seem too chatty, and the jokes etc get tired after a short while.  The problems also seem a bit more challenging that Sundstrom.
- Hammack is in a way half way between the two.  It does not get to proofs until page 113, which seems a bit late --- speaking as someone who has not taught a "proof class" before.  Again congruence is introduced before equivalence relations.   I really wish there is a solution manual.

These are my first impressions, *not criticisms*.  I'd be most appreciative for feedbacks and comments from those who have taught such a class using these books -- why do you pick one over the others?  feedback from students?  advice on how to teach such a class/use these books?

Thanks!

Comment: This might succeed on the Mathematics Educators stack

Comment: Here or on Math Educators, I'd also suggest adding more specific questions. I mean, I've taught proofs from Hammack; I liked it and I'll do it again; it's nice for the students that it's free online, in particular. But I'm not sure specifically what you want to know about it.

Comment: Thanks @Misha.  I added additional comments to clarify what information I am looking for.